# Need assistance with this 'Invalid Syntax error'

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

A part of my code keeps resulting in a invalid syntax error. can someone give it quick look over?

```
def outputheader(name,days,roomtype):
   print"Name : "+name+"\nNumber of days : "+str(days)+"\nRoom Typr : "
   if(roomtype=='A'):
       print "AC\n"
   else:
       print "Regular\n"
```

it seems to have an issue with `print"Name`

any help is Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using python 2 syntax with python 3. This program is valid python 2 where quoted strings can follow the `print` keyword. But in python 3, `print` is a named function and must be called as such.

```
print("Name : "+name+"\nNumber of days : " + str(days) + "\nRoom Typr : ")
```

Since python 2 is past end-of-life, its best to fix the prints (and ditch tuturials showing you the old python way of doing things).